# How do i add the same indexes from two lists together?

Tags: python, list

So I know the title sounds a bit dumb, but what I am trying to do is have two lists add together the same indexes from both lists, so if I had list1[ 2, 3, 4], and list2[5, 6, 7], they would add together within the function and then give me the sums, compare them to the minimum value, and then determine whether or not the function is true or false.

```
def lock_and_key(key_cuts, lock_pinning, minimum):
    for v1 in key_cuts:
        for v2 in lock_pinning:
            sum = abs(v1 + v2 -6)
            if sum > minimum:
                return False
    else:
        return True

if lock_and_key([2.1, 3.5, 2.7], [4.1, 2.5, 3.2],  0.25):
    print('Unlocked.')
else:
    print('Still locked.')**
```

I got it set down for the most part, but the issue I am dealing with is that the lists can varying amounts of variables, so I cannot set in stone the indexes like list1[0] + list[0].

Comment: Because you are using nested for loops, you are pairing the first key cut with _each_ lock pinning, and then the second key cut with _each_ lock pinning, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try out python's build-in [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) method, it joins together the same indexes of an iterable, then u could just do this:

```
def lock_and_key(key_cuts, lock_pinning, minimum):
    for value_of_key, value_of_lock in zip(key_cuts, lock_pinning)
        sum = abs(value_of_key + value_of_lock -6)
        if sum > minimum:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure to try this out!

Answer (score 3):

If I got it correctly, you want to compare the same index of the each least with each other. For this purpose, you can zip the two arrays together ( if they are same size ) and do the check:

```
def lock_and_key(key_cuts, lock_pinning, minimum):
    for v1, v2 in zip(key_cuts, lock_pinning):
        sum = abs(v1 + v2 - 6)
        if sum > minimum:
            return False
    return True

if lock_and_key([2.1, 3.5, 2.7], [4.1, 2.5, 3.2], 0.25):
    print('Unlocked.')
else:
    print('Still locked.')
```

Comment: Oh thank you I didn't know such a thing existed lol.

Comment: It works now, I also added a if statement comparing the length of lists, and to return the statement false if both lists do not have the same len.